# How to implement an Observable consumer(listener) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am still learning flutter. The following is code from a tutorial. When I call the Authservice profile, it return `Observable<Map<String, dynamic>>`.How to get data inside it for display.

This is what I have done so far.But it returns the whole chunk.But I want to get each pair seperately. For example email,name etc.

````
AuthService.profile.listen((value){
    print(value);
});
//This is my solution so far
---------------------------------------------------------------------

//This is my code

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<FirebaseUser> get getUser => _auth.currentUser();
  //Stream<FirebaseUser> get user => _auth.onAuthStateChanged;

  Observable<FirebaseUser> user; //firebase user
  Observable<Map<String, dynamic>> profile; //custom user data in firestore
  PublishSubject loading = PublishSubject(); // Push new value manulay

  AuthService() {
    user = Observable(_auth.onAuthStateChanged);
    profile = user.switchMap((FirebaseUser u) {
      if (u != null) {
        return _db
            .collection('users')
            .document(u.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .map((snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        return Observable.just({});
      }
    });
  }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example about how to access a Map of type < String, dynamic > in Dart:

```dart
foo() {
    Map<String, dynamic> user = {
      "uid":7,
      "username": "nasser",
    };

    print('${user.toString()}'); // {uid: 7, username: nasser}
    print('${user['uid']}'); // 7

    // You can loop inside Map and do whatever 
    // you want with the key and the value; print them,
    // Or create a UserModel object from them..:
    user.forEach((key, value) => print('$key: $value'));
    // forEach's output:
    // uid: 7
    // username: nasser
}
```

---

**Update to the question's specific case:**

According to this code:

```dart
AuthService.profile.listen((value){
    print(value);
});
```

you are accessing the Class itself, this will not work(unless the function 'profile' is static, which is not here), so **first thing you need to create an instance from "AuthService" class before using it**. And as you will need this same-object to be available inside all your app, a single-shared-object, **you need to create it at the end of the file which has "class AuthService" inside**, see this and read the comments:

```dart
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  //..
  //..
} // THIS IS THE CLOSING OF "class AuthService {"

// Add this at the end of the file that you are 
// saving "AuthService" class in, SO YOU WILL BE CREATING 
// A SHARED OBJECT(KINDA BLOC) that you can access from 
// other classes without creating a new instance, just 
// by importing "AuthService class" file.
// This thing has a nickname called 'Singleton' but needs some
// little work to be a perfect Singleton, but it's enough here:
final authService = AuthService();
```

Now the 'authService' object is ready to be used. So inside the widget that you will use the user-profile data in, let's say homeScreen or whatever, **you need to import the file that contains 'AuthService class' and** `final authService = AuthService();`.

Then feel free to access **a**uthService object(NOT the **A**uthService class, see the small/capital letters) as it's created already, and you made it available inside 'HomeScreen' by `import 'auth_service.dart';`, see this code and comments:

```dart
// Import AuthService class, I assume that this is the file name and location
import 'auth_service.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  // Define a var with same type as the Observable to store its data:
  Map<String, dynamic> _userProfile;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Listen to Observable which called "profile" and once this
    // Observable get updated, it will update "_userProfile" too,
    // setState here is important, otherwise you will need a streamBuilder
    // to see the changes on screen:
    authService.profile.listen((v) => setState(() => _userProfile = v));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // WAIT TILL THE FETCHING FROM FIREBASE FINISH
    // THEN YOU WILL BE ABLE TO SEE THE RESULT
    print('${_userProfile.toString()}');

    _userProfile.forEach((key, value) => print('$key: $value'));

    return Container(
       child: Text(
          _userProfile.toString(),
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well cant use that solution

Comment: Can you explian how to apply it to the above code?Because when I try you solutions it always return me a null

Comment: see my update, if not clear just leave a comment, best of luck.